# PowerShell script to check folders for files and email if found

Tags: powershell

I'm still pretty new to PS and with the assistance of the internet, have come up with this script that will check a couple shares for files that get hung up.

We have an app that will grab any files in these shares every 5 minutes, if the top file gets stuck in a folder, they all get stuck in that folder.  It's not a big deal unless hours go by and we don't notice.

So far I have it checking the shares and Writes the files that are stuck, if any.  I would like it to email (O365) a couple of us if a file is older than 10 min.

```
$path = '\\server\folder\filefolder\ReadyForProd' 
$path2 = '\\server\folder\filefolder\ReadyForStage'
$path3 = '\\server\otherfolder\filefolder2\ReadyForProd' 
$path4 = '\\server\otherfolder\filefolder2\ReadyForStage'
$stats = 0 
$msg = '' 
$days = 0
$hours = 0 
$minutes = 10
$files = @(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $path, $path2, $path3, $path4 -Include '*.*' | ?{ $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).AddHours(-$hours).AddMinutes(-$minutes) -and $_.psIsContainer -eq $false}) 
if ($files -ne $null) { 
    $f_names = [System.String]::Join('|',$files) 
    $msg = 'Message: ' + $f_names 
    $stats = $files.Count 
} 
Write-Host $msg 
Write-Host "Statistic: $stats"
```

I'm just missing the part where I need to add the output to an email and send off...

Comment: look into `send-mailmessage`

Comment: Yep, that worked!  Now I am wondering if there is a way I can structure that email into displaying that there is a number of files stuck in the specific share?   I currently have the email saying "Files Stuck: #"